# Getting percent of employee's salary within department

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to create a report that displays information about what part of the salary in percentage terms each employee receives within the department in which they work, using analytical functions.

```
SELECT EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME, EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME, EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID, 
DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME, EMPLOYEES.SALARY,
(SALARY/SUM(SALARY)) * 100  over (partition by DEPARTMENT_ID) AS "PercentWithinDepartment"
FROM HR.EMPLOYEES
FULL JOIN HR.DEPARTMENTS ON EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID = DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID
```

I get an "ORA-00923 FROM keyword not found where expected" error but I think it's not my only mistake within this task.

I cannot provide a code snippet of database but this can be run against the HR sample schema.

[image]

My request is to help me figure out mistake to complete this task properly.

Answer (score 2):

The immediate issue is that your `over` clause is in the wrong place:

```
(SALARY/SUM(SALARY)) * 100  over (partition by DEPARTMENT_ID)
```

should be

```
(SALARY/SUM(SALARY) over (partition by DEPARTMENT_ID)) * 100
```

But the reference to `DEPARTMENT_ID` in there is ambiguous as that column is in both tables, so it should be:

```
(SALARY/SUM(EMPLOYEES.SALARY) over (partition by DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID)) * 100
```

You might want to consider using table aliases to make the code a bit shorter.

You may also want to round (or truncate/floor) the percentages to, say, one or two decimal places.

I'm not sure you really want a full outer join though - that will include all departments with no employees (e.g. 'Recruiting'). A left outer join looks more appropriate - so 'Kimberley Grant', who is not linked to any department, will still be included.

---

> I have to calculate percent about what part of the salary employee get within all organization and im confused why do i get "not a single-group group function" error here

Because the version you added as a comment has:

```
SALARY/SUM(EMPLOYEES.SALARY)*100
```

which is the aggregate form of the function, not the analytic form. As you don't want to aggregate here, you still need an `over` clause to make it analytical, but that can be empty:

```
SALARY/SUM(EMPLOYEES.SALARY) over () * 100
```

And you can of course do both together:

```
select employees.first_name,
  employees.last_name,
  employees.department_id, 
  departments.department_name,
  employees.salary,
  salary / sum(employees.salary) over (partition by departments.department_id) * 100 as "PercentWithinDepartment",
  salary / sum(employees.salary) over () * 100  as "PercentWithinOrganization"
from hr.employees
left join hr.departments on employees.department_id = departments.department_id;

FIRST_NAME           LAST_NAME                 DEPARTMENT_ID DEPARTMENT_NAME                    SALARY PercentWithinDepartment PercentWithinOrganization
-------------------- ------------------------- ------------- ------------------------------ ---------- ----------------------- -------------------------
Jennifer             Whalen                               10 Administration                       4400                     100                .636389933
Michael              Hartstein                            20 Marketing                           13000              68.4210526                1.88024299
Pat                  Fay                                  20 Marketing                            6000              31.5789474                .867804455
...
Kimberely            Grant                                                                        7000                     100                1.01243853
```

You might also want to add an `order by` clause...

Comment: SELECT EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME, EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME, EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID, 
DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME, EMPLOYEES.SALARY,
SALARY/SUM(EMPLOYEES.SALARY)*100 AS "PercentWithinOrganization"
FROM HR.EMPLOYEES 
FULL JOIN HR.DEPARTMENTS ON EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID = DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID

Comment: I have to calculate percent about what part of the salary employee get within all  organization and im confused why do i get "not a single-group group function" error here

Comment: @HelloGoodBye - posting code in comments isn't ideal as it's hard to read; and this should possibly have been a separate question. However, it's fairly simple, so I've updated the answer to show how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have HR schema (but I have Scott) so - here's how. I'm using SQL*Plus' formatting capabilities to make it look prettier.

```
SQL> set numformat 999g990d00
SQL> break on deptno on dname
SQL> compute sum of pct_sal on deptno
SQL>
SQL> select e.deptno, d.dname, e.ename, e.sal,
  2    sum(e.sal) over (partition by e.deptno) dept_sal,
  3    --
  4    round((e.sal / sum(e.sal) over (partition by e.deptno)) * 100, 2) pct_sal
  5  from emp e join dept d on d.deptno = e.deptno
  6  order by e.deptno, e.ename;
```

Result:

```
     DEPTNO DNAME          ENAME              SAL    DEPT_SAL     PCT_SAL
----------- -------------- ---------- ----------- ----------- -----------
      10,00 ACCOUNTING     CLARK         2.450,00    8.750,00       28,00
                           KING          5.000,00    8.750,00       57,14
                           MILLER        1.300,00    8.750,00       14,86
*********** **************                                    -----------
sum                                                                100,00
      20,00 RESEARCH       ADAMS         1.100,00   10.915,00       10,08
                           FORD          3.000,00   10.915,00       27,49
                           JONES         2.975,00   10.915,00       27,26
                           SCOTT         3.000,00   10.915,00       27,49
                           SMITH           840,00   10.915,00        7,70
*********** **************                                    -----------
sum                                                                100,02
      30,00 SALES          ALLEN         1.600,00    9.400,00       17,02
                           BLAKE         2.850,00    9.400,00       30,32
                           JAMES           950,00    9.400,00       10,11
                           MARTIN        1.250,00    9.400,00       13,30
                           TURNER        1.500,00    9.400,00       15,96
                           WARD          1.250,00    9.400,00       13,30
*********** **************                                    -----------
sum                                                                100,01

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

(Sum isn't exactly 100% because of rounding.)

Answer (score 1):

I might be mistaking, but it seems to me that all you need is to use ratio_to_report analytic function. Try this one please

```
SELECT E.FIRST_NAME, E.LAST_NAME, E.DEPARTMENT_ID, 
       D.DEPARTMENT_NAME, E.SALARY,
       100 * ratio_to_report(e.salary) over (partition by   d.department_id)
  FROM HR.EMPLOYEES e
  JOIN hr.departments d 
    on e.department_id = d.department_id
 order by d.department_id;
```